# VBA: Why does SlideRange.Export only export single slide?

Tags: vba, export, powerpoint

I am writing a macro that allows me to export a PowerPoint slide range to a new file. I am using the SlideRange.Export function for this.

Can you offer advice on why the macro currently only exports a SINGLE SLIDE, rather than the entire selection?

```
Sub SaveSlideSelectionPPT()

Dim shortFile As String
Dim longFile As String
Dim nameOnly As String
Dim answer As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim mySlides As SlideRange
    
'Defining parameters
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set mySlides = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
nameOnly = objFso.GetBaseName(ActivePresentation.Name) & "_Excerpt"
shortFile = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & nameOnly
longFile = shortFile & ".pptx"
i = 1

'Checking if file exists
While objFso.FileExists(longFile)
    nameOnly = objFso.GetBaseName(ActivePresentation.Name) & "_Excerpt" & i
    shortFile = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & nameOnly
    longFile = shortFile & ".pptx"
    i = i + 1
Wend

'Creating file
mySlides.Export shortFile, "PPTX"
Set newPres = Presentations.Open(longFile)

Set objFso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Slides.Export is for exporting slides to graphic formats. Creating a filesystem object is not necessary. See this page for a working routine to do this kind of thing: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/3/copy-selected-slides-into-new-powerpoint-presentation

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to save the presentation to a new name, delete all the slides that are NOT selected, then save again.

Here's the basics. You'll need to modify this to suit your own file-naming conventions. You could also store the name of the original presentation and re-open it afterward if you wish.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim cSlides As New Collection
    
    With ActivePresentation
    
        ' Save to a new file name
        .SaveAs "c:\temp\newfile.pptx"
            
        ' Collect all of the UN-selected slides
        For x = .Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
            If Not IsSelected(.Slides(x).SlideIndex, ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange) Then
                cSlides.Add .Slides(x)
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' Delete the collected, UN-selected slides
    For x = cSlides.Count To 1 Step -1
        cSlides(x).Delete
    Next
    
    ' Save the modified presentation
    ActivePresentation.Save
    
End Sub

Function IsSelected(lSlideIndex As Long, oSlideRange As SlideRange) As Boolean
' Returns True if the slide at index lSlideIndex in the selected sliderange is selected
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim x As Long
    
    For x = 1 To oSlideRange.Count
        If oSlideRange(x).SlideIndex = lSlideIndex Then
            IsSelected = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```